# Rails magic iterating over signular partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), a partial is built under the name "app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb" and by placing the below code in the show view of article, Rails knows to iterate through each comment and use the correct partial. How does it know that? I tried changing the partial name to something else besides the singular form of comment and it didn't work. Is this some type of Rails magic I should memorized or is there an explanation?

```
<%= render @article.comments %>
```

I also tried to render `'comments/comment'` instead and it doesn't work, but why would `'comments/form'` work later on in the guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections):

> Partials are very useful in rendering collections. When you pass a collection to a partial via the :collection option, the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection:

In your example, `<%= render @article.comments %>` is a shorthand for writing `<%= render partial: "comment", collection: @article.comments %>`

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit of shorthand using Rails convention.

This is a long form of writing the same thing.

```
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= render partial: 'comment', locals: { comment: comment } %>
<% end %>
```

You could also use collections in your renders.

```
<%= render partial: 'comment', collection: @article.comments %>
```

You can read a bit more on the options in the guide;

[Layouts and rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

and the documentation for the implementation here;

[Partial Renderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)